# Changing logo on all SharePoint Online site via PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

Is it possible to create a script that will loop through all the sites in a site tenancy to replace the logo that is attached to each one.  I'm unable to locate any useful commands in the SPO Commandlet set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below snippet to set the site logo

```
$ClientContext.Web.SiteLogoUrl = "http://logourl";
$ClientContext.Web.Update()
$ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()
```

Below snippet can be used to get all sites

```
$SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "PassWord" -AsPlainText -Force 
$Cred = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials("UserName", $SecurePassword) 
$ClientContext = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext("SiteUrl") 
$ClientContext.Credentials = $Cred

$Web = $ClientContext.Web 
$ClientContext.Load($Web) 
$ClientContext.ExecuteQuery() 

function Get-SPOAllWebs{ 
    Param( 
    [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext]$ClientContext, 
    [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web]$Root 
    ) 

    $Webs = $Root.Webs 
    $ClientContext.Load($Webs) 
    $ClientContext.ExecuteQuery() 

    ForEach ($w in $Webs) 
    { 
        #Logic to update SITELOGO
        Get-SPOAllWebs -RootWeb $w -Context $ClientContext
    } 
}
```

Comment: Was this taken from a blog?  I think I came across something like this when googling.  What are the dependencies?  Get-SPOAllsites for instance isn't an OOB command as far as I can see but an additional script from TechNet. https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Script-to-get-All-Webs-in-c2c1cdaf/view/Reviews  What else would I need to install?

Comment: You need to recursively query to get all the webs.. hence we need to create a function and call it. The initial source was from a blog which I modified and using it.

Answer (score 0):

## this one works for me: https://github.com/t1llo/change_logo_SharePointOnline-PS

```
#Setup the context
$Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl)
$Ctx.Credentials = $Credentials

#Get the Root web
$Web = $Ctx.Web
$Ctx.Load($Web)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

#Function to change Logo for the given web
Function Update-Logo($Web)
{
    #Update Logo
    $Web.SiteLogoUrl = $LogoURL
    $Web.Update()
    $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

full code on https://github.com/t1llo/change_logo_SharePointOnline-PS